# Outlook / Office Add-in fails with error: AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET == SOLVED

Tags: office365, single-page-application, office-js, outlook-web-addins

---

We currently have an Office 365 Outlook add-in deployed in our environment that authenticates against Azure Active Directory.  In testing a Windows 10 (1909) upgrade with Office (1908) client installed, we encountered this error that rendered our add-in useless.

***AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request.***

---

---

---

### Issue:

Outlook add-in on (specifically) Windows 10 version 1909 with Outlook Office version 1908 cannot successfully load an add-in that uses SSO to authenticate against AAD.  Authentication fails.

### Symptoms:

During the authentication process within the Outlook Add-in pane, Outlook pops out of the client to a new Edge browser window directed to autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com and displays the following error: *AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resolution:

To correct the problem, the following AppDomain needs to be added to the add-in’s manifest file and reloaded within the Outlook client:

```
<AppDomain>https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com</AppDomain>
```

---

## Notes:

- The authentication provider changed when the Outlook client’s add-in
  rendering engine moved from IE to Edge.
- We specifically tested the Outlook 1908 client running on Windows 10 1909 only.  I
  suspect it affects the Outlook Client on Windows 10 where the
  following condition is met: ***Windows 10 ver. >= 1903 & Office 365
  ver >= 16.0.11629*** ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins)).  This page also discusses
  potential Edge issues, but not this one specifically.
- I assume this would impact all add-ins for Office like Excel, Word,
  etc. but have not tested this.
- The add-in running within a web browser, Outlook mobile client for
  iOS and Android, and Outlook client for Mac are currently not
  affected as they do not get redirected to autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com.
- Fiddler traces of a working Windows 10 and Outlook client versus the
  upgraded one coupled with [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1#specify-domains-you-want-to-open-in-the-add-in-window) clued us into the
  solution
- For an add-ins using AAD credentials to authenticate in browsers,
  Outlook client (Mac & PC) and Outlook mobile client, these must be in
  the add-in’s manifest file:

  `<AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>` (Browsers)

  `<AppDomain>https://device.login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>` (Mobile Outlook)

  `<AppDomain>https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com</AppDomain>` (Outlook on Windows 10 with Edge rendering engine )
- Be sure to increment the `<version/>` number in the add-in's manifest
  file so that centrally managed and store based add-in's will receive
  the updated manifest.